# Running server and clients on one machine (netbeans 8.1)

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I have a problem to run a server and clients in one (mac) machine. I can run the server but when I run the client it give me an error `java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)`
as far as I know that there is somthing call ssh that need to be used but I don't know how to use it to do solve this. 
Thanks

```
public class WRRCourseWork {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DatagramSocket IN_socket = new DatagramSocket(3000);
        DatagramSocket OUT_socket = new DatagramSocket(5000);
        IN_socket.setSoTimeout(0);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        while (true) {
            //recive the message 

            IN_socket.receive(packet);
            String message = new String(buffer);
            System.out.println("Got message: " + message.trim());

            // send the message 
            String host = "";
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            DatagramPacket OUT_Packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, addr, 5000);
            OUT_socket.send(OUT_Packet);
            System.out.println("Sending Message: "+ message.trim());
        } 

    } catch (Exception error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

...

```
    public class Messages {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("hiiiiiii");
        //String host = "localhost";
        try {
            while (true) {
                InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                String message = "Hello World";
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, addr, 4000);
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(4000);
                socket.send(packet);
                //socket.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception error) {
            // catch all errors
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That error most probably means that the port you have assigned to the client application is already in use. However, this error is not related to SSH.  To help you further, please post the code snippet you are working with and the steps you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you might want to change here:

1) You are sending a UDP packet on port 4000 from your client but listening on port 3000 in your server(receiver) code. Ports should be same.

2) There might be another instance of your server code running in another Netbeans tab or from your terminal may be, which is already bound to the port. Please ensure that you have only one instance running for your server code. This will resolve your 'Address already in use error'

3) I also added 'Thread.sleep(500)' in the client(sender) code in the infinite while loop that you have set up. Without this, the code was ending up with a 'Bad File Descriptor' error on my machine. Probably it was a conflict with the Socket handle running into a problem with the infinite loop in place.

With these changes, data exchange between client and server is working fine.